# Paypal SetExpressCheckout doesn't go for Guest Checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I tried to use the Classic API and setup the `SetExpressCheckout` parameters:

```
(SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole, LANDINGPAGE=Billing, USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard)
```

I receive a `RedirectUrl` for Credit Card payment (#checkout/signup) but that page requires that the users create an account.

Is it possible change for a guest checkout (#checkout/guest) without requiring user registration?

Comment: What country is your account based in, and what country is the buyer account based in that you're working with?  Have you checked to ensure "PayPal Account Optional" is enabled in your PayPal account profile?

Comment: The country is Portugal, for both. 
Sincerely, I don't know. I read lots about that, but the only similar option I found was in the "Business setup" the option  "Payment processing: You’re going to process all payments, including credit cards, through PayPal."

Comment: It's possible they don't offer Guest Checkout for merchants in Portugal.  Check your PayPal account profile under Payment Receiving Preferences.  You should see an option for "PayPal Account Optional" that can be set to On/Off.  Make sure this is turned on.